# SQL Query - Limited by another SQL query of a different data type

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need some help on this one.  I have a query that I need to make work but I need to limit it by the results of another query.

```
SELECT ItemID, ItemNums
FROM dbo.Tables
```

ItemNums is a varchar field that is used to store the strings of the various item numbers.

This produces the following.

```
ItemID     ItemNums
1           1, 4, 5
2           1, 3, 4, 5
3           2
4           4
5           1
```

I have another table that has each item number as an INT that I need to use to pull all ItemIDs that have the associated ItemNums

Something like this.

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.Tables
WHERE ItemNums IN (4,5)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If possible, you should change your database schema.  In general, it's not good to store comma delimited lists in a relational database.

However, if that's not an option, here's one way using a `join` with `like`:

```
select *
from dbo.Tables t 
    join dbo.SecondTable st on ', '+t.ItemNums+',' like '%, '+st.ItemNumId+',%'
```

This concatenates commas to the beginning and end of the `itemnums` to ensure you only match on the specific `ids`.

Comment: Thanks for that bit of help. Fixing the structure is the best option in this case as there could be hundreds of items in the ItemNums field.

Answer (score 0):

I personally would recommend normalizing your dbo.tables.
It would be better as:

```
ItemID       ItemNums
1            1
1            4
1            5
2            1
```

etc.

Then you can use a join or a sub query to pull out the rows with ItemNums in some list.

Otherwise, it's going to be a mess and not very fast.